# Why is our xbox one recent app list mixed between users?

Tags: xbox-one

After the recent Xbox One home screen update, my account recent app list on the home screen shows games that were played on other profiles. Before the update, the recent games list showed only games or app that were used by the current logged in profile.

What setting can I change to get the old behavior?